# How to give ontouch effect to div while URL changes

Tags: jquery, angularjs, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I am making a phonegap application in which I need to give the effect on touch start to touch end in a div.

My problem : I used a touch effect inkdrops (https://github.com/akhilarjun/InkDrops) But in my case that is not working because on click to div immediately change the URL (as tested on chrome) due to which angular controller changes and hence the effect does not take place.

I want suggestion for some new effect along with the remedy to problem mentioned above.

Here is the div that I wanted to give effect

HTML:

```
 <div style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 1px #ccc;margin: 0 12px;">
           <div class="opporMain  inkMe" style="margin:0px" >
                <div class="opporHeader" >

                    <div class="opporHeading">This is the Header</div>
                </div>
                <div class="lineDiv"></div>
                <div class="opporContent"  >
                    <div class="contentContainer">
                        <div class="contentStatus">
                            Hi this is the content
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="clearContent"></div>
                    <div class="contentUpdateTime"><img class="timeIcon" src="images/drawable-mdpi/time-icon-mdpi.png" alt="clock">&nbsp;Time  ago</div>
                    <div class="clearContent"></div> 
                    <div class="contentUpdateBy">updated by <font color="black">here goes the name</font></div>     

                    </div>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="lineDiv"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.commentIcon{
   content:url(images/drawable-xxhdpi/comment.png);
   height:16px;
   width:16px;
   }

.timeIcon
{
    content:url(images/drawable-xxhdpi/time-icon-xxhdpi.png);
   height:12px;
   width:12px;
}
.opporMain {

margin-left:12px;
    margin-right:12px;
}
.opporHeader {
    clear:both;
    /*position:relative;*/
    display:inline-block;
    display:block;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break :break-all;
    min-height:40px;

}
.circleIcon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    margin-top:6px;
    display:block;
    -wsebkit-border-radius: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius: 14px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    background-color:#ffb400;
    margin-left: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Roboto-Light;
    font-size:18px; 
    color:White;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 28px;
}
.opporHeading {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Roboto-bold;
   /* font-weight: 700;*/
    font-size: 16px;    
    column-rule: #000;231f20;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-right: 4px;
}
.lineDiv {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.opporContent {

    background-color:#ffffff;
    overflow:hidden;

    padding-bottom:12px;    

}
.opporComment
{
    height:40px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    overflow:auto;
    margin-left:12px;
    margin-right:12px;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.contentContainer
{
    /*display:inline-block;*/
}
.contentStatus
{


    float:left;
    font-family:Roboto-R;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#4554a5;
    margin-top:10px;   
    margin-left:8px;

}
.clearContent
{
    clear:both;    
}
.contentUpdateTime
{

    float:right;
    font-family:Roboto-Light;
    font-weight:100;
    font-size:12px;    
    color:#b1b3b6;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-right:10px;

}
.contentUpdateBy
{
    float:right;
    font-family:Roboto-Light;
    font-size:14px;    
    font-weight:300;
    color:#b1b3b6;
    margin-top:4px;
    margin-right:10px;

}    
.opporCommentContent
{
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    font-family: Roboto-Medium;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size:14px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:6px;
    color:#4f4f51;
}
.commentIcon
{
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin-top:14px;
    margin-left:8px;
}
.opporCommentDetails
{
    float:right;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    font-family: Roboto-Light;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#b1b3b6;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tvaibhav/vjxe9ozq/

Answer (score 0):

Try using Angular-Ripple

**[Demo Link](http://nelsoncash.github.io/angular-ripple/)**

This creates the ripple effect as you want

https://github.com/nelsoncash/angular-ripple/tree/master

Comment: I implemented indrop which is very similar to this but this does not work in my case as I have the problem of URL change on click and hence ripple often don't come.

Comment: can u reproduce in fiddle ..bcoz above fiddle link doesnt make things clear

Comment: actually I cant It has a page redirection that created the problem and also I have a extenal javascript dependency.

Comment: try to make some prototype not the exact on e